# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path Kotlin Coroutines with MVVM & Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using retrofit with Kotlin and coroutines using MVVM pattern. This is the first time I'm using retrofit and kotlin. My issue is I'm calling a news api and getting this error even though I've tried solving my problem on my own but didn't get any proper solution.

Json Response:

```
{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 3923,
-"articles": [
-{
-"source": {
"id": null,
"name": "Finextra"
},
"author": "Editorial Team",
"title": "Solaris Digital Assets wins Bitwala as digital asset custody partner",
"description": "Solaris Digital Assets GmbH, a 100% subsidiary of Solarisbank AG, today announced that it has won Bitwala, Germany’s crypto-banking flagship company, as a partner for its digital asset custody solution.",
"url": "https://www.finextra.com/pressarticle/85033/solaris-digital-assets-wins-bitwala-as-digital-asset-custody-partner",
"urlToImage": "https://www.finextra.com/about/finextra-logo-alt-16-9.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2020-11-17T14:28:00Z",
"content": "Solaris Digital Assets GmbH, a 100% subsidiary of Solarisbank AG, today announced that it has won Bitwala, Germanys crypto-banking flagship company, as a partner for its digital asset custody solutio… [+3321 chars]"
},
-{
-"source": {
"id": null,
"name": "Seeking Alpha"
},
"author": "Ophelia Research",
"title": "Power Corporation Of Canada Is Still A Buy",
"description": "Wealthsimple continues to grow through social media platforms and referral incentives. Power Corporation of Canada continues to grow its investments in start-ups.",
"url": "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4389643-power-corporation-of-canada-is-still-buy",
"urlToImage": "https://static2.seekingalpha.com/uploads/2020/11/15/saupload_EWZQEwLYN4dxnan8QPFcRnpuNy_nvcN-PV5mrbjb97co4v9-QgGK8ZN8UqwxzO3oSPoiDkwnvSMFsyqKGu06-S1TGHHydTAz8VkQXaY5-FjSbTa5-qzCROck4sPk2ZeSD6rYIL1P.png",
"publishedAt": "2020-11-17T14:21:26Z",
"content": "Power Corporation of Canada (OTCPK:PWCDF) is a diversified financial services company that pays out solid dividends due to strong established brands and still has the potential for growth given its i… [+6824 chars]"
}]}
```

Retrofit Builder:

```
object RetrofitBuilder {

    private const val BASE_URL = "http://newsapi.org/v2/"

    private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build() //Doesn't require the adapter
    }

    val apiService: ApiService = getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java)
}
```

Api Interface:

```
interface ApiService {
    @GET("sources/apikey")
    suspend fun getTopHeadlines(): Model
}
```

Api Helper:

```
suspend fun getTopHeadlines() = apiService.getTopHeadlines()
```

Main Repository:

```
suspend fun getTopHeadlines() = apiHelper.getTopHeadlines()
```

ViewModelFactory:

```
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)) {
        return MainViewModel(MainRepository(apiHelper)) as T
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown class name")
}
```

MainViewModel:

```
fun getTopHeadlines() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    emit(Resource.loading(data = null))
    try {
        emit(Resource.success(data = mainRepository.getTopHeadlines()))
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        emit(Resource.error(data = null, msg = exception.message ?: "Error Occurred!"))
    }
}
```

Model Class:

```
data class Model(val status: String,val totalResults: Int,val articles: List<Article>)
```

Article Class:

```
data class Article(
    val source: Source,
    val author: String,
    val content: String,
    val description: String,
    val publishedAt: String,
    val title: String,
    val url: String,
    val urlToImage: String
)
```

Source Class:

```
data class Source(
    val id: Any,
    val name: String
)
```

Main Activity:

```
viewModel.getTopHeadlines().observe(this, Observer {
    it?.let { resource ->
        when (resource.status) {
            Status.SUCCESS -> {
                Log.e("MainClass","Data caught: "+it.message);
                // resource.data?.let { users -> retrieveList(users) }
            }
            Status.ERROR -> {
                Log.e("MainClass","Exception caught: "+it.message);
                Toast.makeText(this, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            Status.LOADING -> {
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: mmm... your method to fetch the Model data looks nice because the json starts by "{" so is an object, not an array... so please, check in the logs using the Verbose mode with key "okhttp" your response is a 200... and use try catch with retrofit try { yourCall } catch(ex: HttpException and IOException to handle internet connection if you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. Judging by [this documentation](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines) and by your code, there are plenty things wrong here, so I will go into more detail below.

1. Your `Model` class that you created:

   - Here is the POJO structure that I generated for the Json you provided..

Something like this:

```
data class Base(
    @SerializedName("status") val status: String,
    @SerializedName("totalResults") val totalResults: Int,
    @SerializedName("articles") val articles: List<Articles>
)

data class Articles(
    @SerializedName("source") val source: Source,
    @SerializedName("author") val author: String,
    @SerializedName("title") val title: String,
    @SerializedName("description") val description: String,
    @SerializedName("url") val url: String,
    @SerializedName("urlToImage") val urlToImage: String,
    @SerializedName("publishedAt") val publishedAt: String,
    @SerializedName("content") val content: String
)

data class Source(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: String,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String
)
```

Model class is done. Moving on to your Retrofit code.

2. Your `Retrofit` instance:

   - `@GET(sources/apikey)` line is completely wrong. Nothing like that exists in documentation and you won't be able to get anything out of it. In order to get what you need, you need to reference `top-headlines` or `sources` or `everything`.
   - Your `object RetrofitBuilder` can be simplified in some ways.
   - You need to query ApiKey together with your request which you are not doing
   - You need to query Country together with your request which you are not doing as well

Lets apply the changes then. (I am using `top-headlines` here since it fits our model class):

```
// This is much simplified version of what you have written.
interface NewsApi {
    // Here we use correct API endpoint.
    @GET("top-headlines")
    suspend fun getTopHeadlines(
        // This is how you Query necessary parameters for APIs
        // In our case, we need to query Country + apiKey
        @Query("country") country: String = "us",
        @Query("apiKey") apiKey: String = "%InsertYourApiKey%"
    ): Response<Base> // Response<Base> is simply a class that allows you to read API's response codes, body and other details that you might need for processing response information.

    companion object {
        fun getInstance(): NewsApi {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://newsapi.org/v2/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(NewsApi::class.java) // Creation doesn't have to be separate, you can have it in here for more concise code.
        }
    }
}
```

After these changes, all you have to do:

1. Insert your API key into interface where I have written `%InsertYourApiKey`
2. Use the following code anywhere you need:

...

```
val newsApi = NewsApi.getInstance()
val response = newsApi.getTopHeadlines()

// Do whatever you need with your response.
```

Comment: "It is incorrect from Gson standpoint. Each field needs to be Annotated with @SerializedName". You actually don't. The GsonConverterFactory will manage it itself based on the class field names. You just need to make sure they match your Json. So it is safer to use `@SerializedName` if you want to name the field differently in your class, but not required

Comment: Everything was already correct at my end like end point etc but I missed the "Serialized" annotations. Thanks for pointing that out.